# How to use scons for continuous integration?

Tags: continuous-integration

The code (using C++) is developed using eclipse and for continuous integration, we are looking up in TFS (using its feature of CI).

Comment: Do you mean you want to set up a continuous integration build with Eclipse and TFS 2013?

Comment: yes, want to set up a continuous integration build. But in TFS.
Some details are:-
Compiler used        -   IAR and GCC,
Coding Language   -   C++,
IDE                        -   Eclipse
Repository             -   GIT

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to set up a continuous integration build with Eclipse and TFS. This can be achieved as TFS can run Ant or Maven builds. But you'll need to set up your own build server.

After setting up the build server, you need to enable Ant or Maven builds on the build server and define your CI build. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155784(v=vs.120).aspx#) link for details.

More information of Team Foundation Server Plug-in for Eclipse, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913026(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: thanks for help.
I have already setup Build server (created controler and agent). But donot know how to proceed further in creating build definition, as we are using Git repositry, and  project is of C++ developing using eclipse.